# createRange within an iframe but results outside the iframe

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging, iframe, range, copy-paste

Says that I want to insert some HTML into the `body` element inside an `iframe` element.
I use following code:

```
var selection = iframe.contentWindow.document.selection;
var range = selection.createRange();

range.collapse(false);
range.pasteHTML('<h1>hello</h1>');
```

I suspect that the newly created `h1` element should appear inside the `iframe`, but
it was inserted into the top level of `body` element, ie. the container of `iframe`, not the `iframe` itself.

This issue seems to occur only in IE.

Comment: That should work. Have you tried focussing the iframe first?

Comment: I tried, but still no good results. I seems that ie get confused the outside body element with inside one. Hi, Tim, I saw someone asked your similar question before (???), what's going on there?

Comment: I have seen IE get confused about which frame but not when the correct frame is explicitly focussed. Have you got a demo page I can see?

Comment: Actually this occurs with a ticy wyswyg editor based on jquery. I forked it from a dead project. You can find out the source code [here](https://github.com/kuno/jquery.uEditor). There also some demo page at the original site, like [this](http://www.upian.com/upiansource/ueditor/demo/)

Comment: Use a timer to delay the operation until the iframe is ready: `setTimeout(function(){range.pasteHTML('<h1>hello</h1>');}, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

> Use a timer to delay the operation until the iframe is ready:

```
setTimeout(function(){range.pasteHTML('<h1>hello</h1>');}, 0);
```